# Bootable USB not working?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, rufus

I used rufus to make the bootable drive so I can change my laptop to ubuntu instead of windows XP but my USB drive won't even boot itself.

Comment: Assuming it's an old computer (because XP), with Rufus you need to select the option "MBR for BIOS". Then change the boot order to boot from the USB stick.

Comment: You need to press certain keys to access BIOS and override normal HDD boot procedures. The keystrokes vary depending on machine so we need to know what your computer make and model is.

Comment: spam escape lol, it brings up the options menu